# Python remove Square brackets and extraneous information between them

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, python-3.6

I'm trying to handle a file, and I need to remove extraneous information in the file; notably, I'm trying to remove  brackets `[]` including text inside and between bracket `[]`  `[]` blocks, Saying that everything between these blocks including them itself but print everything outside it.

### Below is my text File with data sample:

```
$ cat smb
Hi this is my config file.
Please dont delete it

[homes]
  browseable                     = No
  comment                        = Your Home
  create mode                    = 0640
  csc policy                     = disable
  directory mask                 = 0750
  public                         = No
  writeable                      = Yes

[proj]
  browseable                     = Yes
  comment                        = Project directories
  csc policy                     = disable
  path                           = /proj
  public                         = No
  writeable                      = Yes

[]

This last second line.
End of the line.
```

### Desired Output:

```
Hi this is my config file.
Please dont delete it
This last second line.
End of the line.
```

### What i have tried based on my understanding and re-search:

```
$ cat test.py
with open("smb", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    start = line.find( '[' )
    end = line.find( ']' )
    if start != -1 and end != -1:
      result = line[start+1:end]
      print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./test.py
   homes
   proj
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with one regex

```
import re

with open("smb", "r") as f: 
    txt = f.read()
    txt = re.sub(r'(\n\[)(.*?)(\[]\n)', '', txt, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(txt)
```

regex explanation:

`(\n\[)` find a sequence where there is a linebreak followed by a [

`(\[]\n)`  find a sequence where there are [] followed by a linebreak

`(.*?)` remove everything in the middle of `(\n\[)` and `(\[]\n)`

`re.DOTALL` is used to prevent unnecessary backtracking

---

**!!! PANDAS UPDATE !!!**

The same solution with the same logic can be carried out with pandas

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# read each line in the file (one raw -> one line)
txt = pd.read_csv('smb',  sep = '\n', header=None)
# join all the line in the file separating them with '\n'
txt = '\n'.join(txt[0].to_list())
# apply the regex to clean the text (the same as above)
txt = re.sub(r'(\n\[)(.*?)(\[]\n)', '\n', txt, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(txt)
```

Answer (score 5):

Read the file into a string,

```
extract = '''Hi this is my config file.
Please dont delete it

[homes]
  browseable                     = No
  comment                        = Your Home
  create mode                    = 0640
  csc policy                     = disable
  directory mask                 = 0750
  public                         = No
  writeable                      = Yes

[proj]
  browseable                     = Yes
  comment                        = Project directories
  csc policy                     = disable
  path                           = /proj
  public                         = No
  writeable                      = Yes

[]

This last second line.
End of the line.
'''.split('\n[')[0][:-1]
```

will give you,

```
Hi this is my config file.
Please dont delete it
```

`.split('\n[')` splits the string by the occurrence of `'\n['` set of characters and `[0]` selects the upper description lines.

```
with open("smb", "r") as f: 
     extract = f.read()
     tail = extract.split(']\n')
     extract = extract.split('\n[')[0][:-1]+[tail[len(tail)-1]
```

will read and output,

```
Hi this is my config file.
Please dont delete it
This last second line.
End of the line.
```

Comment: Thanks Akash, but how to read a file and then process it, can you put that way.

Comment: `with open("smb", "r") as f:
    extract = f.read().split('\n[')[0][:-1]` will do the trick, I've added a [:-1] to remove a space that was coming. smb is a file which contains the input. Please consider accepting my answer if it answers your question. Thanks!

Comment: @kulfi, kindly go through the updated code above! Thanks!

Comment: @kulfi, can you give me an example?

Comment: i have edited my `smb` file in the post, thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks Akash, it gives me syntax error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when i do `print(extact)`

Comment: I guess it's `print(extract)` @kulfi, it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged `pandas`, let's try that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('smb', sep='----', header=None)

# mark rows starts with `[`
s = df[0].str.startswith('[')

# drop the lines between `[`
df = df.drop(np.arange(s.idxmax(),s[::-1].idxmax()+1))

# write to file if needed
df.to_csv('clean.txt', header=None, index=None)
```

Output (`df`):

```
                             0
0   Hi this is my config file.
1        Please dont delete it
18      This last second line.
19            End of the line.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over file lines and collect them into some list unless reach line wrapped into brackets, then concatenate collected lines back:

```
with open("smb", "r") as f:
    result = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("[") and line.endswith("]"):
            break
        result.append(line)
    result = "\n".join(result)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey but it prints the same file content not desired one.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want everything before the first `[` and after the last `]`. If it is not the case please let me know and I will change my answer.

```
with open("smb", "r") as f: 
    s = f.read()
    head = s[:s.find('[')]
    tail = s[s.rfind(']') + 1:]
    return head.strip("\n") + "\n" + tail.strip("\n") # removing \n
```

This will give you the desire output.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 5
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

[Program finished] ```works well if used within function

Comment: @Subham well yes, "return" only works inside a function. If you want to use it outside of function you can replace the return with print.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to first match the the square brackets like `[homes]`, then match all lines that do not  only contain `[]` as that is the end marker.

You could get the match without using `(?s)` or using `re.DOTALL` to prevent unnecessary backtracking and replace the match with an empty string.

```
^\s*\[[^][]*\](?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\[]$).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\[]$\s*
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of line
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitepace chars
- `\[[^][]*\]`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `[^\S\r\n]*\[]$` match 0+ times a whitespace char except newlines and match `[]`
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars without a newline
- `\[]$` Match `[]` and assert the end of the line
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/65u8xu/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8K9o4i)

*Code example*

```
import re

regex = r"^\s*\[[^][]*\](?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\[]$).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\[]$\s*"

with open("smb", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    result = re.sub(regex, "", data, 0, re.MULTILINE)
    print(result)
```

*Output*

```
Hi this is my config file.
Please dont delete it
This last second line.
End of the line.
```

Answer (score 3):

On [Regex101](https://regex101.com) you can test this:

`(^\W)+?\[[\w\W]+?\[\](\W)+?(\w)`

In code its like

`import re
------------------------------------------------------------↧-string where to replace--
result = re.sub(r"(^\W)+?\[[\w\W]+?\[\](\W)+?(\w)", "", input_string, 0, re.MULTILINE)
----------------------↑-this is the regex------------↑-substitution string-------------`

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Since you've tagged `pandas` and stipulate that the text comes before & after the square brackets we can use `str.contains` and use a boolean to filter out the rows that fall in between the first & last square bracket.

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_file,sep='\t',header=None)

idx = df[df[0].str.contains('\[')].index

df1 = df.loc[~df.index.isin(range(idx[0],idx[-1] + 1))]

                             0
0   Hi this is my config file.
1        Please dont delete it
18      This last second line.
19            End of the line.
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got the indexing wrong. Apart from that, the code seems fine.

Try:

```
start=0
targ = ""
end=0
with open("smb", "r") as file:
    for line in file: 
        try:  
            if start==0:
                start = line.index("[")
        except:
            start = start
        try:  
            end = line.index("]")
        except:
            end = end
        targ = targ+line

targ = targ[0:start-1]+targ[end+1:]
```

This should work. Let me know if anything goes wrong. :)

Comment: where `targ` is defined?

Answer (score 3):

Using Pandas :

```
df = pd.read_csv('smb.txt', sep='----', header=None, engine='python',names=["text"])

res = df.loc[~df.text.str.contains("=|\[.*\]")]
print(res)
text
0   Hi this is my config file.
1   Please dont delete it
18  This last second line.
19  End of the line.
```

**Explanation** : Exclude rows that contain either `=` or contain a starting bracket (`[`) that may or may not be followed by characters(`.*`) and have a closing bracket (``` ]``). the backslash ( ``````) tells python not to treat the brackets as special characters

With Python only, the same regex pattern is used, with an extra line to take care of empty entries:

```
import re
with open('smb.txt') as myfile:
    content = myfile.readlines()
    pattern = re.compile("=|\[.*\]")
    res = [ent.strip() for ent in content if not pattern.search(ent) ]
    res = [ent for ent in res if ent != ""]
    print(res)
['Hi this is my config file.',
 'Please dont delete it',
 'This last second line.', 
 'End of the line.']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is probably one of the cleanest ways you can do it.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
res = '\n'.join(re.findall(r'^\w.*', Path('smb').read_text(), flags=re.M))
```

Explanation:

`Path` creates a `Path` object to the file. `Path.read_text()` opens the file reads the text and closes the file. The file contents are passed to `re.findall` which uses the `re.M` flag to look at each line in the file to validate again the pattern `'^\w.*'` which will only take lines that begin with a word character. This eliminates lines that begin with white-space or brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try `r"(?s)\s*\[[^\[\]]*\](?:(?:(?!\[[^\[\]]*\]).)+\[[^\[\]]*\])*\s*"`
Replace `r"\n"`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/KviYRk/1)

Comment: It's easier to take what you want instead of omitting what you don't in this case. `'\n'.join(re.findall(r'^\w.*', Path('smb').read_text(), flags=re.M))`

Comment: .findall(r'^\w.*  gets aparnot body of tags. But OP has not definition of tags or open/end define so most aswers are gesses and accepted is worst gessu